# Transparent background for SWFLoader

Tags: apache-flex, flash, transparency, swfloader

I created a "Loading" spinner in a SWF.  I display this spinner in my main application SWF using SWFLoader.  How do I make the SWFLoader transparent?  Currently it uses Flex's default background color even though I've set `backgroundAlpha="0"`.

My spinner SWF's main MXML: (Note the use of `backgroundAlpha`)

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:Controls="Controls.*" width="30" height="30" backgroundAlpha="0">
    <Controls:Spinner id="ctrlSpinner" />  <!-- spinner logic encapsulated in a component -->
</mx:Application>
```

My application SWF's main MXML:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" height="801">
    <mx:SWFLoader x="10" y="173" id="swfSpinner" autoLoad="true" scaleContent="true" >
        <mx:source>SWFs/LoadingSpinnerApp.swf</mx:source>
    </mx:SWFLoader>
</mx:Application>
```

Note that the Spinner control itself is transparent.  There's just something about the SWFLoader that causes it to ignore my backgroundAlpha setting.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was doing the correct thing -- Flex just wasn't copying the latest version of my spinner SWF to the bin of my main app.  Instead it had been holding on to a previous version built before I added the transparency.

I manually copied the new spinner SWF to the main app's bin and then it worked!

Comment: I hear ya on this one.... I've had issues similar to this with the compiler as well.  More or less when using Modules.  I'm hoping this is improved in Flex4!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is within the Spinner component you must be setting the background color or alpha in there and that's causing your loader to have a background color.  if you not setting it then set it because it probably defaults to an alpha of 1.  when I do the following I don't get any background but when I change the alpha to 1 the black background appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
layout="absolute" backgroundAlpha="1" 
backgroundColor="#000000">
    <mx:Text id="textBox" text="Hey World"/>
</mx:Application>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
layout="absolute" backgroundColor="#ffffff">

    <mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#ff0000" width="200" 
height="200" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
        <mx:SWFLoader x="10" y="173" id="swfSpinner" 
autoLoad="true" scaleContent="true" source="DebuggerTest.swf"/>
    </mx:Canvas>

    </mx:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Although this wasn't the solution to my problem, I'm sure it is the solution in most other cases.